# Example CmakeList.txt for using GoogleTest with C project

Tags: unit-testing, gcc, cmake, googletest, clion

I understand googletest is for C++ Unit testing. However, I hope that I can use it for C Unit testing as well. I created a Hello world project with the following CmakeList.txt file which obviously didn't work.

One of the issue was /usr/bin/cc complained about C++ syntax such as "include < limits >" not found. I guess it though it was supposed to be limits.h to be C stylistically correct.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(untitled C CXX)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE 1)

include_directories(../googletest/googletest/include)

add_executable(untitled main.c)
link_libraries(untitled gtest gtest_main)
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

int return_one()
{
    return 1;
}

TEST(test_case, test_name)
{
    ASSERT_EQ(return_one(), 1);
}
```

Comment: What is your question? It would be good if you provide a minimal example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: GoogleTest is a C++ library, you cannot use it with C program. However, if your C program is correct for C++ too, you may compile it with C++ compiler: `set_source_files_properties(main.c PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)`. This would allow you to use GoogleTest in your code.

Comment: Googletest can certainly be used to unit-test C APIs, but your post suggests
that perhaps you haven't got the basic concepts of unit-testing quite straight to
begin with. To get useful help, edit your post to show us what is in `main.c`.